# How to find elements existing in two lists but with different indexes

Tags: python, algorithm, list, language-agnostic

I have two lists of the same length which contains a variety of different elements. I'm trying to compare them to find the number of elements which exist in both lists, but have different indexes.

Here are some example inputs/outputs to demonstrate what I mean:

```
>>> compare([1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 3, 2, 1])
4
>>> compare([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
0
# Each item in the first list has the same index in the other
>>> compare([1, 2, 4, 4], [1, 4, 4, 2])
2
# The 3rd '4' in both lists don't count, since they have the same indexes
>>> compare([1, 2, 3, 3], [5, 3, 5, 5])
1
# Duplicates don't count
```

The lists are always the same size.

This is the algorithm I have so far:

```
def compare(list1, list2):
    # Eliminate any direct matches
    list1 = [a for (a, b) in zip(list1, list2) if a != b]
    list2 = [b for (a, b) in zip(list1, list2) if a != b]

    out = 0
    for possible in list1:
        if possible in list2:
            index = list2.index(possible)
            del list2[index]
            out += 1
    return out
```

Is there a more concise and eloquent way to do the same thing?

Comment: What is the result of compare([1, 3], [3, 3])?

Comment: @JuanLopes It would be 0, since the last elements in both lists would be filtered out and removed first and don't count.

Answer (score 1):

since duplicates don't count, you can use `set`s to find only the elements in each `list`. A `set` only holds unique elements. Then select only the elements shared between both using `list.index`

```
def compare(l1, l2):
    s1, s2 = set(l1), set(l2)
    shared = s1 & s2 # intersection, only the elements in both
    return len([e for e in shared if l1.index(e) != l2.index(e)])
```

You can actually bring this down to a one-liner if you want

```
def compare(l1, l2):
    return len([e for e in set(l1) & set(l2) if l1.index(e) != l2.index(e)])
```

**Alternative:**

Functionally you can use the `reduce` builtin (in python3, you have to do `from functools import reduce` first).  This avoids construction of the list which saves excess memory usage.  It uses a lambda function to do the work.

```
def compare(l1, l2):
    return reduce(lambda acc, e: acc + int(l1.index(e) != l2.index(e)),
                  set(l1) & set(l2), 0)
```

A brief explanation:

`reduce` is a functional programming contruct that reduces an iterable to a single item traditionally.  Here we use `reduce` to reduce the `set` intersection to a single value.

`lambda` functions are anonymous functions.  Saying `lambda x, y: x + 1` is like saying `def func(x, y): return x + y` except that the function has no name.  `reduce` takes a function as its first argument.  The first argument a the `lambda` receives when used with `reduce` is the result of the previous function, the `accumulator`.

`set(l1) & set(l2)` is a set consisting of unique elements that are in both `l1` and `l2`.  It is iterated over, and each element is taken out one at a time and used as the second argument to the `lambda` function.

`0` is the initial value for the accumulator.  We use this since we assume there are 0 shared elements with different indices to start.

Answer (score 1):

This python function does hold for the examples you provided:

```
def compare(list1, list2):
    D = {e:i for i, e in enumerate(list1)}
    return len(set(e for i, e in enumerate(list2) if D.get(e) not in (None, i)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont claim it is the simplest answer, but it is a one-liner.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [1, 3, 2, 4]

print len(np.unique(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[a,b] for a,b in zip(l1,l2) if a!= b]))))
```

I explain:

```
[[a,b] for a,b in zip(l1,l2) if a!= b]
```

is the list of couples from `zip(l1,l2)` with different items. Number of elements in this list is number of positions where items at same position differ between the two lists.

Then, `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable()` is for merging component lists of a list. For instance :

```
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[3,2,5],[5,6],[7,5,3,1]]))
[3, 2, 5, 5, 6, 7, 5, 3, 1]
```

Then, discard duplicates with `np.unique()`, and take `len()`.